# how to fill JavaScript array with database data using php

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

here is php code to connect to database

```
<?php    
$host = "localhost";
$user = "admin";
$password = "";
$dbname = "test";

$con = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $dbname) or die ('Could not connect to the database server' . mysqli_connect_error());
?>
```

And here is where i want to insert database data into JavaScript array

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var array = [<?php
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT name FROM users");
while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {
    unset($name);
    $name = $row['name'];
    echo '<p>'.$name.'</p>';
}
?>];
document.write(array);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

First save the data to another array and use JSON type to pass it to JS

try this code,

```
<?php
while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {
    $array2js[] = $row['name'];
}
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var array = JSON.parse("<?=json_encode($array2js)?>");
    console.log(array);
</script>
```

good day~

Comment: Dont need to parse it `JSON.parse` its already json

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone This function decodes JSON.

Comment: Yeah it's like doing `var a = JSON.parse("[]")` when you can just do `var a = []` without it as json_encode returns json :/

Answer (score 1):

You should use [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php):

> json_encode — Returns the JSON representation of a value

```
<?php
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT name FROM users");

$json = array();
while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {
    $json[] = $row['name'];
}
?>
```

Then in your javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var array = <?= json_encode($json) ?>;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `array` in the JS code is displaying `[0] => '<p>name</p>'`. You are not building the array correctly, so you need to remove the `p` element, and make it space separated.

---

### EDIT

As suggested, `[json_encode][1]` would be a better solution, look at this example:

```
<?php
// get results from db
$name = $row['name'];
$age = $row['age'];
$phone = $row['phone'];
// create array
$array = array($name, $age, $phone);
// encode array
$json = json_encode($array);
?>

<script>
    var array = <?php echo $json; ?>;
    document.write(array);
</script>
```

This will output:

```
name,age,phone
```

Comment: @LawrenceCherone ^^ I've added a new section to my answer

Answer (score 0):

It is common to use Ajax and JSON response to populate javascript variable with DB data.
But please try following

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var array = [
      <?php
      $result = array();
      $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT name FROM users");
      while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {
            unset($name);
            $name = $row['name'];
            $result[] = "'$name'";
      }
      echo impode(",", $result);
      ?>
      ];
      for(var i =0; i < array.length; i++)
      {
        document.write("<p>" + array[i] + "</p>");
      }

</script>
```